# Kubernetes list all container id

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

I have set a N replica pods running workers celery. Now I need to setup a cron JOB running a celery producer script then I need to be able to get a container id for container using a tagged image.

So how to list all container id for multi-containers (container A and container B) pod where container A is using a tagged image C.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

One way is to do "kubectl get pods" to get all pod names, then do "kubectl get pod " for each pod. See [this documentation page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#get) for information about the templating arguments you can use with "kubectl get pod" to just select the fields you want (for example, image).

Comment: Now i'm using something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35797906/kubernetes-list-all-running-pods-name/35803557#35803557 and my container have always the same name. :)