# kubernetes list all running pods name

Tags: kubernetes

I looking for the option to list all pods name

How to do without awk (or cut). Now i'm using this command

```
kubectl get --no-headers=true pods -o name | awk -F "/" '{print $2}'
```

Comment: Actually your command is quite good (comparing to suggested solutions below). You can replace the `awk` with **grep -Po '\/\K.+'** to [keep selection after \K](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html), and also remove `--no-headers=true`

Comment: I find `cut -d/ -f2` is easier to type than either the `awk` or the `grep`.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You can use the go templating option built into kubectl to format the output to just show the names for each pod:

```
kubectl get pods --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}'
```

Comment: Thanks, Can't find any reference about go-template.

Comment: http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_get.html describes the different output types and gives an example of using the template. The templating language itself is described at https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/ and you can run `kubectl describe -o yaml pod <NAME>` to see the fields that are available to operate on.

Comment: You have a whitespace too much in the first template declaration:
{{range .items}}

Answer (score 254):

Personally I prefer this method because it relies only on kubectl, is not very verbose and we don't get the pod/ prefix in the output:

```
kubectl get pods --no-headers -o custom-columns=":metadata.name"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your answer would be more useful to a greater number of users if you explain why you prefer this method.

Comment: Indeed, I have added some explanation on why I do prefer this approach

Comment: This is much nicer than the usual template solution.

Comment: I like this one much better

Comment: It should be a `.` not a `:` for the filter, i.e. `.metadata.name`

Comment: The semicolon is needed, since custom-columns expects a header and then a jsonpath expression. indeed, the json expression could have a leading dot, but it does not seem necessary for it to work.

Answer (score 73):

Get Names of pods using `-o=name` Refer this [cheatsheet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/) for more.

`kubectl get pods -o=name`

Example output:

```
pod/kube-xyz-53kg5
pod/kube-xyz-jh7d2
pod/kube-xyz-subt9
```

To remove trailing `pod/` you can use standard bash `sed` command

`kubectl get pods -o=name |  sed "s/^.\{4\}//"`

Example output:

```
kube-xyz-53kg5
kube-pqr-jh7d2
kube-abc-s2bt9
```

To get podname with particular string, standard linux `grep` command

`kubectl get pods -o=name | grep kube-pqr | sed "s/^.\{4\}//"`

Example output:

`kube-pqr-jh7d2`

With this name, you can do things, like adding alias to get shell to running container:

`alias bashkubepqr='kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pods -o=name | grep kube-pqr | sed "s/^.\{4\}//") bash'`

Comment: Actually, you can just do:
`kubectl get pods -o name`
then use the output `pod/mypod-xxxxx` like this :

`kubectl describe pod/mypod-xxxxx`

Comment: Using awk instead of sed would make it working with anything (you are ignoring the first 4 characters, but what about another resource than pods, with a longer or shorter name?). With awk : `kubectl get pods -o=name |  awk -F "/" '{print $2}'`

Comment: As @Brou pointed out, `resource/name` is a valid format to kubectl to specific objects, so you don't need to trim the `pod/` prefix.

Comment: I like the answer, buyt for the sed expression, why not just "s/^....//g"? Be kind to your own eye :)

Answer (score 48):

You can use custom-columns in output option to get the name and --no-headers option

```
kubectl get --no-headers=true pods -l app=external-dns -o custom-columns=:metadata.name
```

Comment: `custom-columns` is much more streamlined way of doing this.

Comment: Why you use `-l`?

Answer (score 19):

You can use [-o=name](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/) to display only pod names. For example to list proxy pods you can use:

```
kubectl get pods -o=name --all-namespaces | grep kube-proxy
```

The result is:

```
pod/kube-proxy-95rlj
pod/kube-proxy-bm77b
pod/kube-proxy-clc25
```

Comment: OP said he just wanted to get rid of the leading "pod/" part...

Answer (score 17):

Here is another way to do it:

```bash
kubectl get pods -o=name --field-selector=status.phase=Running
```

The `--field-selector=status.phase=Running` is needed as the question mention all the **running** pod names. If the **all** in the question is for all the namespaces, just add the `--all-namespaces` option.

Note that this command is very convenient when one want a quick way to access something from the running pod(s), such as logs :

```bash
kubectl logs -f $(kubectl get pods -o=name --field-selector=status.phase=Running)
```

Comment: Actually this is the correct answer, considering the status of this question in Feb 2023.

Answer (score 16):

There is also this solution:

```
kubectl get pods -o jsonpath={..metadata.name}
```

Comment: This is the most concise way for sure, and meet's the OP's requirement of not piping through another tool, but could be problematic if there's more than one pod name returned. Appending a newline, and wrapping the name + newline in a range clause ensures readability: 
`kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='{range.items[*]}{..metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}'`

Comment: @DaleC.Anderson - running `kubectl -n pool-agents get pods -o jsonpath='{range.items[*]}{..metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}'` returns this error: `error: error parsing jsonpath {range.items[*]}{..metadata.name}{\n}{end}, unrecognized character in action: U+005C '\'` any idea why?

Comment: @Tar no idea. If you quote it as written, you shouldn't get that error, but if you skip the single quotes surrounding the json expression, it produces that error. Maybe its your shell, or maybe you missed some chars?  If the error persists, ask a new Q. Thats what this site is for .

Comment: @DaleC.Anderson ok found it: need to swap single quotes with double quotes in all places in Windows' console (CMD and PowerShell). This works: `kubectl -n pool-agents get pods -o jsonpath="{range.items[*]}{..metadata.name}{'\n'}{end}"`

Answer (score 10):

Get all running pods in the namespace

```
kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase=Running --no-headers -o custom-columns=":metadata.name"
```

From [viewing, finding resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#viewing-finding-resources).

You could also specify namespace with ***-n <namespace name>***.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I want - just pod names without pod/ prefix

Answer (score 5):

If you want to extract specific `container`'s `pod` name then
A simple command can do all the hard work

```
kubectl get pods --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{end}}' --selector=app=<CONTAINER-NAME>
```

Just replace `<CONTAINER-NAME>` with your service container-name

Answer (score 4):

jsonpath alternative

```
kubectl get po -o jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{@.metadata.name}{end}" -l app=nginx-ingress,component=controller
```

see also:
[more examples of kubectl output options](https://gist.github.com/so0k/42313dbb3b547a0f51a547bb968696ba)

Answer (score 1):

```
kubectl get pods --no-headers -o name
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, In our case we have kept pods inside different namespace, here to identify the specific pod or list of pods we ran following command-

**Approach 1:**

1. To get the list of namespaces
   `kubectl get ns -A`
2. To get all the pods inside one namespaces  `kubectl get pods -n <namespace>`

**Approach 2:**

Use this command-

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using like below :

```
kubectl get pods -l service=usercontent
```

It brings all pods that related  this service.

Answer (score -2):

```
kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pods | grep mess | awk '{print $1}') /bin/bash


hostname -i
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/list-all-running-container-images/

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath="{.items[*].spec.containers[*].image}" |tr -s '[[:space:]]' '\n' |sort |uniq  | grep mess

kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{"\n"}{.metadata.name}{":\t"}{range .spec.containers[*]}{.image}{", "}{end}{end}' |\
```

sort

feca4d9f-02db-4edf-88a2-6e9d169a92a9

You can get all the values of a ConfigMap in one line by using the kubectl get command with the -o go-template option to iterate over the values and print them on separate lines. Here's an example:

```
kubectl get configmap MY_CONFIG_MAP -o go-template='{{range $k,$v := .data}}{{$k}}={{$v}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}'

kubectl get configmap MY_CONFIG_MAP -o jsonpath='{.data}'
```