# How do I get a single pod name for kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm looking for a command like "gcloud config get-value project" that retrieves a project's name, but for a pod (it can retrieve any pod name that is running). I know you can get multiple pods with "kubectl get pods", but I would just like one pod name as the result.

I'm having to do this all the time:

```
kubectl get pods       # add one of the pod names in next line
kubectl logs -f some-pod-frontend-3931629792-g589c some-app
```

I'm thinking along the lines of "gcloud config get-value pod". Is there a command to do that correctly?

Comment: why don't you simply grep the output?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the grep command to filter any output on stdout. So to get pods matching a specified pattern you can use a command like this:

```
> kubectl get pods --all-namespaces|grep grafana
```

Output:

> ```
> monitoring      kube-prometheus-grafana-57d5b4d79f-smkz6               2/2       Running   0          1h
> ```

To only output the pod name, you can use the `awk` command with a parameter of `'{print $2}'`, which displays the second column of the previous output:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces|grep grafana|awk '{print $2}'
```

To only display one line you can use the `head` command like so:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces|grep grafana|awk '{print $2}'|head -n 1
```

Comment: Thanks Markus. Is there a way to just output the "kube-prometheus-grafana-57d5b4d79f-smkz6" value?

Comment: Okay great! Just one more issue. I have 3 pods running and it's listing all 3 pods. Can I output just one of the pod's name? (Sorry, I'm a complete novice at grep)

Comment: sure :) another command to the rescue: head -n 1. updated answer. or you could provide the full pod name in grep. and there are many more ways to do it, like Diegos answer.

Comment: On Windows, use `findstr` in place of `grep`.

Answer (score 15):

There are many ways, here are some examples of solutions:

`kubectl get pods -o name --no-headers=true`

`kubectl get pods -o=name --all-namespaces | grep kube-proxy`

`kubectl get pods -o go-template --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}'`

For additional reading, please take a look to these links:

[kubernetes list all running pods name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35797906/kubernetes-list-all-running-pods-name)

[Kubernetes list all container id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35773731/kubernetes-list-all-container-id?noredirect=1&lq=1)

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/list-all-running-container-images/

Answer (score 0):

- This will output the last pod name :
  `kubectl get pods -o go-template --template ' {{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}' | awk '{print $1}' | tail -n 1`
- if you want to fetch logs for a pod:
  `kubectl logs -f` `kubectl get pods -o go-template --template ' {{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}' | awk '{print $1}' | tail -n 1`

*just run the command with a single quotes.*

Links:

1. [kubernetes list all running pods name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35797906/kubernetes-list-all-running-pods-name)
2. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/list-all-running-container-images/

Hope this helps!!